# r group_by and count() creating a column of True or False

Tags: r, dplyr, count

I am trying to use count() function within dplyr to count values of certain type and it is creating a column of true or false which is not what I was expecting.

For example this is my sample code

```
data("starwars")
head(starwars)

starwars %>%
   group_by(sex) %>%
      dplyr::summarise(
          EyeColor = count(eye_color == "blue")
                      )
```

I am seeing a column EyeColor$x with True/False value which is not what I was expecting. Any suggestions ? Thanks.

[image]

I was expecting something results like this

```
sex            Freq
female         6
male           12
hermaphroditic NA
NA             1
```

Comment: Are you looking for `sum` instead of `count`?

Comment: @MartinGal, which ever would give me the count . A factor could have a value "2" , how would sum work in that case, I am not sure.

Answer (score 2):

You can simply use `tally()` so that you can count the frequencies of whichever variable(s) you give to `group_by()` as below (the first 10 rows are printed here):

```
starwars %>%
  group_by(sex, eye_color) %>% tally()
   sex            eye_color     n
   <chr>          <chr>     <int>
 1 female         black         2
 2 female         blue          6
 3 female         brown         5
 4 female         hazel         2
 5 female         yellow        1
 6 hermaphroditic orange        1
 7 male           black         7
 8 male           blue         12
 9 male           blue-gray     1
10 male           brown        15
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: actually the solution from Martin Gal , to use `sum` worked